# Show whether a series is convergent or divergent using the comparison test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm not sure how to apply the comparison test to show whether the following sum converges or diverges:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)^2 \log(n+1)}$$

I have found that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} = \frac{1}{4} + \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$$

and that since the absolute value of $\frac{1}{(n+1)}$ is $< 1$, the sum converges.

Applying the comparison test,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)^2 \log(n+1)} < \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} \text{ for all } n \ge 2$$

From my understanding, this only allows me to show that $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)^2 \log(n+1)}$ is convergent.

How can I show that the sum from $1$ to infinity is also convergent ?

Comment: Adding the $n =1$ term just adds $1/(4\log(2))$ to the sum, which certainly can't make it diverge.

Comment: One important point : when you use the comparison test, you compare the **terms** of the sums, **not** the sums themselves. So just say $0<\frac{1}{(n+1)^2\ln(n+1)} \le \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$, the sum $\sum_n \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$ is convergent (Riemann), so the other sum must be convergent. The fact that the sum begins at index $1$ instead of index $2$ doesn't matter, the inequality just has to be true for $n\ge N_0$ for some $N_0\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: I corrected your improper way of typesetting $\log$.  Note that $a\log b$ and $a\log(b)$, coded as a\log b and a\log(b), have different amounts of space to the right of $\log$, and the former has space not found in $a log b$, coded (improperly) as "a log b".  But I wonder why you excluded plus signs and "equals" signs from within MathJax. I see people doing that here and I've never understood why.  Is there some on-line manual telling you to do it that way?

Comment: Michael - I'm very new to this and still getting to grips with using MathJax! Point noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: After a few terms, all remaining terms of $1/{(n+1)^2}{\log(n+1)}$ (all are positive) are smaller than corresponding terms of $ 1/(n+1)^2,$ which are positive.

Comment: I realised this - thank you. It is now clear that adding a few finite terms wouldn't make a difference to the convergence of the series

Comment: Please: Write $\log(n+1)$, not $log(n+1). \qquad$

Answer (score 1):

Changing only finitely many terms of a series does not alter whether it converges or not (although it does alter the sum).